# dplyr>Get rows with minimum and maximum of variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame which I want to return `min` and `max` time observations of 
value.

```
df<- data.frame(
   time=c(24594.55, 29495.45, 24594.55, 39297.27, 24594.55, 34396.36, 19693.64, 14792.73, 29495.45),
   Mz=c(-0.04729751, -0.50902297, -0.04376393, -0.22218980, -0.36407263, -0.38341534, -0.34597255, -0.01480776, -0.00999671),
   set_nbr=c(1, 1,1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3))         


library(dplyr)

min_time <- df %>% 
  group_by(set_nbr) %>%
  slice(which(Mz<0))%>%
  filter(rank(time,ties.method="min")==1)%>%
  distinct


min_time 

 ##Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
 ##Groups: set_nbr

      time          Mz set_nbr
## 1 24594.55 -0.04729751       1
## 2 24594.55 -0.36407263       2
## 3 14792.73 -0.01480776       3
```

This works, but when I try to get max_time, strange result comes:

```
max_time <- df %>% 
  group_by(set_nbr) %>%
  slice(which(Mz<0))%>%
  filter(rank(time,ties.method="max")==1)%>%
  distinct

max_time 

##Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
##Groups: set_nbr

        time          Mz set_nbr
##1 24594.55 -0.36407263       2
##2 14792.73 -0.01480776       3
```

`set_nbr` 1, and `max` `time` values are incorrect. I don't know why.

Expected output

```
max_time 

      time            Mz    set_nbr
##1 29495.45 -0.50902297       1
##2 39297.27 -0.22218980       2
##3 29495.45 -0.00999671       3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing with `filter`+`rank`, but do you know about the `arrange` function? Like `df %>% arrange(time) %>% group_by(set_nbr) %>% slice(c(1,n()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
df %>% 
   group_by(set_nbr) %>% 
   filter(time==max(time))
#     time          Mz set_nbr
#1 29495.45 -0.50902297       1
#2 39297.27 -0.22218980       2
#3 29495.45 -0.00999671       3
```

Or

```
 df %>%
    group_by(set_nbr) %>%
    slice(which.max(time))
 #      time          Mz set_nbr
 #1 29495.45 -0.50902297       1
 #2 39297.27 -0.22218980       2
 #3 29495.45 -0.00999671       3
```

Regarding why your code didn't work

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(set_nbr) %>%
    slice(which(Mz <0)) %>%
    mutate(rn = rank(time, ties.method='max'))
 #      time          Mz set_nbr rn
 #1 24594.55 -0.04729751       1  2
 #2 29495.45 -0.50902297       1  3
 #3 24594.55 -0.04376393       1  2
 #4 39297.27 -0.22218980       2  3
 #5 24594.55 -0.36407263       2  1
 #6 34396.36 -0.38341534       2  2
 #7 19693.64 -0.34597255       3  2
 #8 14792.73 -0.01480776       3  1
 #9 29495.45 -0.00999671       3  3
```

If you look at the output, for the 'set_nbr' group '1', there is no '1' for 'rn' as there were ties.  You could do

```
 df %>% 
    group_by(set_nbr) %>%
    slice(which(Mz <0)) %>%
    filter(rn = rank(-time, ties.method='first')==1)
 #      time          Mz set_nbr
 #1 29495.45 -0.50902297       1
 #2 39297.27 -0.22218980       2
 #3 29495.45 -0.00999671       3
```